# Will space-related questions be migrated to SEx.SE (Space Exploration) after it goes public?

Tags: discussion, migration

In two days, [Space Exploration SE](http://space.stackexchange.com) is going public. How will the migration of space-related questions proceed?

---

Note: it is not my fault that the folks have chosen this moniker. After all, we have IT Security.SE (Sec.SE) and nobody complains.

Comment: Not only do they not complain, they are actually [happy about it!](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/a/891/7497)

Comment: Nice title... You know that? *(attracts more people)* o.O :P

Comment: Interesting choice for a name. In French, SEx is considered to be the
best way to explore the Seventh Heaven.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There won't be any:

- Migration to beta sites is discouraged -- beta sites should grow as organically as possible.
- Migration of old questions is also discouraged
- We won't migrate questions which are on-topic here. In the case of a site scope overlap, questions stay where asked.

Comment: Straight from the parent horse's mouth: [Should questions that belong to Public Beta sites be moved there?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90061/should-questions-that-belong-to-public-beta-sites-be-moved-there)

Comment: @DeerHunter 2011. Now we're a bit more wary of migrating to betas. Older betas aren't much of a problem, but it's best to not interfere with newer betas, especially ones which don't have mods. Also, I don't think we get many off topic Space Ex questions here. Most of these questions are on topic because we allow most astronomy questions.

Answer (score 4):

Well I was just about to post my own topic about this.  Space Exploration is being infected by physics questions.  Out of the most recent 10 questions, I can count about 4 or 5 that could be questions here.

I want to let everyone know that we're getting new activity partly because of traffic from there.  I've linked to a number of physics questions, because Space Exploration produces things are repeats from here.

And let me say that the astronomy detail is quite confusing.  Space exploration and astronomy are quite heavily intertwined.

Comment: I wouldn't mind stuff being migrated over, though it's best if it stays on Space Ex if on topic there too (if it's becoming an "infection", it may be time to restrict physics questions). Re:intertwined: It's OK if sites overlap.